# How to Import all the files in a directory with a single command using mysqlimport?

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I'm trying to dump and import some data from a MySQL (5.7) database.

Running the command

```
mysqldump --tab=/mysqldump mydatabase
```

I'm able to get a `.sql` and `.txt` file for each table.

How can I import all the files/tables using `mysqlimport` in a single command?

I have tried `mysqlimport mydatabase /mysqldump` but it does not work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `--tab` option, use general syntax `mysqldump [options] db_name tbl_name ... > dump.sql` instead. You'll get an ordinary sql-script that can be executed via CLI-client `mysql` such way:

```
mysql -u dbauser -p < /path/to/dump.sql
```

Anyway to import different dumpfiles you have to use some shell script that build the list of files in the given directory and then proceed that list one by one like that:

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in /path/to/*.txt
do 
   mysqlimport database $file
done
####
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Are there any specific reasons I should not use `--tab`?

Comment: @macsig Tab- or comma-separated export is useful for cross-platform data migration but if you want to migrate data from one `mysql` server to another export to the sql-script is preferrable. At least because you need no access to the server's filesystem via ftp/scp/sftp as well as shell access to run `mysqlimport`. Common tools like `phpmysqladmin` or `mysqlbench` or `heidisql` can execute script without complications.

Comment: When the file is big, dump.sql is too slow. Loading from txt file could be much faster.